# Issue in DocumentTermMatrix with corpus in German

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, tm

I created a corpus in R using package tm specifying language and encoding as follows:

```
de_DE.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(de_DE.sample), readerControl
    = list(language="de_DE",encoding = "UTF_8"))
de_DE.corpus[36]$content
de_DE.dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(de_DE.corpus,control = list
    (encoding = 'UTF-8'))
inspect(de_DE.dtm[, grepl("grÃ", de_DE.dtm$dimnames$Terms)])
inspect(de_DE.dtm[36, ])
```

If I see the content in `de_DE.corpus[36]$content` of document 36 which has 'ü' the text is shown correctly. e.g. " ...Single ist so die Begründung der Behörde Eine... "

But when I create the **DocumentTermMatrix** (I tried multiple options for encoding and language) I am getting words like "begrÃ" where for example is the word "Begründung". See result after executing `inspect(de_DE.dtm[36, ])`.

```
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 21744)>>

Non-/sparse entries: 102/21642

Sparsity : 100%

Maximal term length: 43

Weighting : term frequency (tf)

Sample :

Terms

Docs begrÃ das dem der die eine einen jobcenter und zum

36     3    4   2  4   8     2    2       4       3  3
```

---

I would appreciate if someone knows how to fix the problem. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which Operating System are you on?

Comment: Windows 10, R Version 3.4.1, package ‘tm’ version 0.7-1

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but here's a potential clue:

    `text <- "Begründung"; Encoding(text) ## [1] "UTF-8"`

Here's what happens if we set the wrong encoding:

    `Encoding(text) <- "latin1"; print(text) ## [1] "BegrÃ¼ndung"`

Comment: After many failed attempts the only solution that I found was:
`de_DE.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(de_DE.sample), readerControl
    = list(language="de_DE",encoding = "UTF_8"))`
`de_DE.corpus <- tm_map(de_DE.corpus, function(x) iconv(x, from='UTF-8', to="latin1"))`
`de_DE.corpus[4]$content`
`de_DE.dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(de_DE.corpus,control = list
    (encoding = 'UTF-8'))`
`inspect(de_DE.dtm[4, ])`

Hope it helps someone having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your input data? Because your code works for me. So I think you have an issue when you are loading it already in de_DE.sample.

```
doc<-c("Single ist so die Begründung der Behörde Eine", "Single Begründung Behörde ")

de_DE.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(doc), readerControl
                       = list(language="de_DE",encoding = "UTF_8"))
de_DE.dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(de_DE.corpus,control = list
                                (encoding = 'UTF-8'))

inspect(de_DE.dtm[1, ])
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 7)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 7/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 10
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
    Terms
Docs begründung behörde der die eine ist single
   1          1       1   1   1    1   1      1
```

Comment: Hi @Dr Vcomas, thanks for your reply. You're right, the problem is already in de_DE.sample. Checking the input data if a consult the encoding with `Encoding(de_DE.sample[36])`, it shows "UTF-8", but if I apply `iconv(de_DE.sample[36], to='UTF-8')` is showing me the characters as "..er single ist so die begrÃ¼ndung der behÃ¶rde". I don't understand why if it detects UTF-8 as the encoding is applying a transformation or how could I the data correctly. Hope with this additional information someone has an idea of how to solve the issue and could help me. :)

Comment: Encoding issues are quite common. You will need to check the process, where is this data coming from, if there is a step where the data is saved with a given encoding, usually ppl extract the data and open it with excel for example, which usually introduces encoding issues, at least from my experience. Check every step of your data process. I hope it helps, you can still consider the question answered. Is not a tm or DocumentTermMatrix issue.